# How should I properly extract and parse subject data from a webpage using python and BS4?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to build a web crawler that collects topic lines from forums. Once it has that, I'd like to display each topic as a new line, with a [*] at the front of each line.

Using BeautifulSoup, I'm able to grab a page and extract the span class "subject". From there however, I'm unsure how to parse out only the subject text and then order it the way I'm trying to.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://boards.4channel.org/sci/"

#send the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:

    #pull the content
    html_content = response.content

    #send the page to BeautifulSoup
    html_doc     = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

    #extract topic data
    topic_spider = html_doc.find_all("span",{"class":"subject"})

    print topic_spider
```

Current results from the crawler look like this:

```
[<span class="subject"></span>, <span class="subject"></span>, <span class="subject">Cigarettes vs. Cannabis</span>, <span class="subject">Cigarettes vs. Cannabis</span>, <span class="subject"></span>, <span class="subject"></span>, <span class="subject"></span>, <span class="subject"></span>, <span class="subject"></span>...
```

I'm trying to order them like this:

```
[*] Topic 1
[*] Topic 2
[*] Topic 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the text of the element is not null then remove the duplicates and sort the list and then traverse and  add `[*]` to the string.
Hope this one you after.If not let me know your expected output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://boards.4channel.org/sci/"

#send the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:

    #pull the content
    html_content = response.content

    #send the page to BeautifulSoup
    html_doc     = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

    #extract topic data
    topic_spider = html_doc.find_all("span",{"class":"subject"})
    data=[]
    for topic in topic_spider:
        if topic.text!='':
             data.append(topic.text)
    mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(data)) #Remove the duplicates here
    mylist.sort(reverse=False) #sort here
    for d in mylist:
        print ('[*]' + d)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

I need to do some further learning on using sorting and keys, it seems.

Comment: @OutlawBandit : Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set comprehension with `:not(:empty)` css pseudo classes. Output is already in alphabetical order but you can always call sort method

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://boards.4channel.org/sci/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")
data = {"[*]" + item.text for item in soup.select('.subject:not(:empty)')}
#data.sort()
```